# Possibility of sending a IOTA transaction from a "micro-controller"?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, iri-legacy-api, internet-of-things, energy-consumption

Since IOTA is designed specifically for IoT, is there a specific library for **micro-controllers** such as `ESP`, such that we can interact (send a transaction) **directly** from a micro-controller to the IOTA Tangle?

And if yes, is there an **existing example**?

**Note 1:** Concerning the task of micro-controller, consider for example grabbing some value (could be temperature, Power,…) by micro-controller and initiate a transaction to certify this value at a specific time.

**Note 2:** Please note that `Raspberry Pi` is **NOT** an option. Instead we intend to use a **micro-controller** such as `ESP8266`.

Answer (score 2):

I am working exactly on this at the moment: https://github.com/embedded-iota/iota-c-light-wallet (but on my fork. I will push it to embedded iota when it works fine.)
The address generation works fine. I have trouble to create a transaction bundle. There are some tricky parts when you work on a MCU without MMU. In my case: STM32F1. 
I also integrated it into RIOT OS. There is also a complete example with subscribing via lora: https://github.com/Citrullin/RIOT/tree/iota_implementation/examples/iota-address-lora
Feel free to fork and ping me on discord. (@citrullin)